Splunk Addon Python Module TypeError
I have this Python code:
# encoding = utf-8

import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
import json

'''
    IMPORTANT
    Edit only the validate_input and collect_events functions.
    Do not edit any other part in this file.
    This file is generated only once when creating the modular input.
'''
'''
# For advanced users, if you want to create single instance mod input, uncomment this method.
def use_single_instance_mode():
    return True
'''

def validate_input(helper, definition):
    """Implement your own validation logic to validate the input stanza configurations"""
    # This example accesses the modular input variable
    # service_plan_id = definition.parameters.get('service_plan_id', None)
    # api_key = definition.parameters.get('api_key', None)
    pass

def collect_events(helper, ew):
    

    # The following examples get the arguments of this input.
    # Note, for single instance mod input, args will be returned as a dict.
    # For multi instance mod input, args will be returned as a single value.
    global opt_service_plan_id
    global opt_api_key
    opt_service_plan_id = helper.get_arg('service_plan_id')
    opt_api_key = helper.get_arg('api_key')
    
    service_plan_id = opt_service_plan_id
    region = "us"
    api_key = opt_api_key
    url = "https://" + region + ".sms.api.sinch.com/xms/v1/" + service_plan_id + "/groups"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(api_key)}
    response = helper.send_http_request(url, 'GET', parameters=None, payload=None,
                                        headers=headers, cookies=None, verify=True, cert=None,
                                        timeout=None, use_proxy=True)
    # get the response headers
    # r_headers = response.headers
    # get the response body as text
    # r_text = response.text
    # get response body as json. If the body text is not a json string, raise a ValueError
    r_json = response.json()
    # get response cookies
    # r_cookies = response.cookies
    # get redirect history
    # historical_responses = response.history
    # get response status code
    r_status = response.status_code
    if r_status !=200:
       # check the response status, if the status is not sucessful, raise requests.HTTPError
       response.raise_for_status()

    # The following examples show usage of check pointing related helper functions.
    # save checkpoint
    #helper.save_check_point(key, state)
    # delete checkpoint
    #helper.delete_check_point(key)
    # get checkpoint
    #state = helper.get_check_point(key)

    # To create a splunk event
    event = helper.new_event(json.dumps(r_json['groups']), time=None, host=None, index=None, source=None, sourcetype=None, done=True, unbroken=True)
    ew.write_event(event)

When I'm running this code I'm receiving this kind of error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/splunk/etc/apps/TA-sinch-addon-for-splunk/bin/ta_sinch_addon_for_splunk/aob_py3/modinput_wrapper/base_modinput.py", line 128, in stream_events
    self.collect_events(ew)
  File "/opt/splunk/etc/apps/TA-sinch-addon-for-splunk/bin/sinchpythonaddontest_1713375439_287.py", line 64, in collect_events
    input_module.collect_events(self, ew)
  File "/opt/splunk/etc/apps/TA-sinch-addon-for-splunk/bin/input_module_sinchpythonaddontest_1713375439_287.py", line 83, in collect_events
    url = "https://" + region + ".sms.api.sinch.com/xms/v1/" + service_plan_id + "/groups"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

and I want to output like this:
"groups": [
    {
      "id": "01HTCSYHRFC7Z7PZ3KJMQC8Y56",
      "name": "Rohit9",
      "size": 2,
      "created_at": "2024-04-01T12:25:36.271Z",
      "modified_at": "2024-04-01T12:25:36.271Z",
      "child_groups": []
    },
    {
      "id": "01HT1TJ2EK6T4N0KC4PDJV4K8H",
      "name": "Rohit3",
      "size": 1,
      "created_at": "2024-03-28T06:04:37.203Z",
      "modified_at": "2024-03-28T06:04:37.203Z",
      "child_groups": []
    },
    {
      "id": "01HT1T90Q5WT5SNM4S253RYS00",
      "name": "Rohit3",
      "size": 0,
      "created_at": "2024-03-28T05:59:40.517Z",
      "modified_at": "2024-03-28T05:59:40.517Z",
      "child_groups": []
    },
    {
      "id": "01HT1T7RB9K15HXNCNFFJ4AA67",
      "name": "YOUR_group_name",
      "size": 0,
      "created_at": "2024-03-28T05:58:59.177Z",
      "modified_at": "2024-03-28T05:58:59.177Z",
      "child_groups": []
    },
    {
      "id": "01HT0YR44GGQTBR21J5KCR8854",
      "name": "Rohit4",
      "size": 1,
      "created_at": "2024-03-27T21:58:35.408Z",
      "modified_at": "2024-03-27T21:58:35.408Z",
      "child_groups": []
    },
    {
      "id": "01HT0YPPNKR567KBDB0YS8CG0B",
      "name": "Rohit4",
      "size": 1,
      "created_at": "2024-03-27T21:57:48.851Z",
      "modified_at": "2024-03-27T21:57:48.851Z",
      "child_groups": []
    },
    {
      "id": "01HT0YNF0MTYBWMY9B93ECYSHC",
      "name": "Rohit4",
      "size": 1,
      "created_at": "2024-03-27T21:57:08.244Z",
      "modified_at": "2024-03-27T21:57:08.244Z",
      "child_groups": []
    },
    {
      "id": "01HT0W025PM8G120QA1Q73SKP0",
      "name": "Rohit4",
      "size": 1,
      "created_at": "2024-03-27T21:10:29.814Z",
      "modified_at": "2024-03-27T21:10:29.814Z",
      "child_groups": []
    },
    {
      "id": "01HT0VFBX0Y9BPHYNBRD6SHQ39",
      "name": "Rohit3",
      "size": 2,
      "created_at": "2024-03-27T21:01:22.720Z",
      "modified_at": "2024-03-27T21:01:22.720Z",
      "child_groups": []
    },
    {
      "id": "01HT0V0C5VB21YEYK6JPN69YQK",
      "name": "Rohit2",
      "size": 2,
      "created_at": "2024-03-27T20:53:11.483Z",
      "modified_at": "2024-03-27T20:53:11.483Z",
      "child_groups": []
    },
    {
      "id": "01HSJS9TS1W8RJ951H0AVKH2QC",
      "name": "RohitpandeyGroup",
      "size": 2,
      "created_at": "2024-03-22T09:54:02.145Z",
      "modified_at": "2024-03-22T09:54:02.145Z",
      "child_groups": []
    }
  ],
  "page_size": 11
}


This error is because service_plan_id is null.  So that presumably means helper was not able to find any argument named 'service_plan_id', so it returned null by default.

but through Add-on Setup Parameters i'm passing
both value
serive_plan_id and api_key
have any solution or anyone solve this issue?

You have not shown how you are setting up the parameters, so I can only guess that you made some mistake.
